# Not able to login remotely to the custom linux box using root user credentials

Tags: linux, ssh, authentication

I am not able to login to my custom Linux system with the root user credentials as it says access denied. I have reset the root password by logging in via the admin user. The message in the syslog says maximum authenticated user exceeded for root. I checked the sshd_login file and that does not have any limit set for maximum remote users. Any insight on it will be appreciated.

This is when logging in to the box over the network via SSH. He only has network access to the device. PermitRootLogin is set to yes in sshd_config.

Comment: This this a console login or an ssh login?

Comment: Is `PermitRootLogin yes` in your sshd_config?

Comment: This is ssh login

Comment: yes PermitRootLogin is yes

Comment: Is the account locked? passwd -S root
Do you have access restrictions on where root can login from ? check /etc/security/access.conf

Comment: I checked it and there is no restriction as such.

Answer (score 0):

you have to make sure you have following enabled:

```
[alexus@XXX Desktop]$ sudo grep ^PermitRootLogin /etc/ssh/sshd_config
PermitRootLogin yes
[alexus@XXX Desktop]$
```

keep in mind that log in remotely as root is *NOT* recommended, you can always create a user and either use `sudo` or `su` to get to root's privileges...

Answer (score -1):

Try to check if  the option

```
PermitRootLogin no
```

is set in /etc/ssh/sshd_config

Comment: I checked that and it is set to yes

Comment: check also the file /etc/securetty
here an explanation for what is used:
[/etc/securetty](http://www.faqs.org/docs/securing/chap5sec41.html)

Comment: I tried with that as well..but still no go